# Sending an image from an application to a webserver

Tags: java, android, web-services, image, base64

I was wondering what the preferred way of sending an image to a webserver from an android application?

I've seen people

- opening up sockets and send the actual image data.
- base64 encoding it and sending it as a string.

What is the preferred way? Can someone post some examples as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing it to an xml file as a base64 string then send it an parse the file on the server and decode the string to an image.

Comment: That's how we send PDF's to our clients a lot of times for our enterprise sales application. We also use SFTP for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP Post is probably the easiest way, sending it as multi-part form data. Makes it easier to receive as well (a bog standard web server can handle it!)